# e(fx)clipse: preference page with javafx

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, e4, efxclipse

Is it possible to create and use preference page abilities in `e4` `javafx` application with `e(fx)clipse`?
I saw some examples how to do this with JFace using extension point `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages` but there no similar extension point in e(fx)clipse target platform.

I use e(fx)clipse 1.2, eclipse luna 4.4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is **no** because JFace is not available in JavaFX and even then this would not work